# UnicodeEncodeError when printing from Django

Tags: python, django, unicode, character-encoding, django-views

Using python interpreter

```
>>> print u'\xe9'
Ã©
```

But if I put the same line inside a Django view, I get

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 0: 
ordinal not in range(128)
```

Why is that?

I'm using Django 1.5.1 and python 2.6.6.

Some background... I have a Django project, that uses a 3rd party module to process some strings, and also prints them. When using the module outside of Django, it works fine, but when using it as part of a Django project, it crashes when trying to print a non-ascii character. I don't really care about the printing, just the other stuff it's doing.

Comment: Where does it print the character and where does it fail?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand your question. Having print u'\xe9' executed in a Django view, will cause the exception.

Comment: But the point is, why would you print in a view? Normally in a view you output to the response.

Comment: As I wrote above, I'm using a 3rd party module (called by the view), that does the printing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Python `print` statement will automatically encode Unicode values to the codec used for `sys.stdout`.

In your console or terminal, the output codec is automatically picked up from the system. If your output is redirected to a *file*, however, the default codec `ASCII` is used.

A Django application running on a server cannot rely on the output codec being set to something that can handle all unicode codepoints. Don't use `print`, use logging instead, and encode explicitly.

If a third-party library is doing this, you need to contact the maintainers and ask them to stop doing this. You could wrap each call to that library with a context manager that swaps out `sys.stdout` with a dummy object (one with a suitable `.encoding` attribute), but that's just a stop-gap measure really:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
from io import BytesIO
import sys

@contextmanager
def capture_stdout_unicode(codec='UTF-8'):
    output = BytesIO()
    output.encoding = codec
    orig, sys.stdout = sys.stdout, output
    try:
        yield output
    finally:
        sys.stdout = orig
```

then use this like:

```
with capture_stdout_unicode() as out:
    api_call_that_prints()

logger.info(out.getvalue())
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. Sorry, I can't upvote your answer - I don't have enough reputation yet :-)

Comment: Not a problem, I already hit the reputation cap for today. :-)